# Getting Gowalla Check-in history using API

Tags: php, api, curl, geolocation, social-networking

I have been playing around with the Gowalla API, and was wondering if anyone has found a way to get a list of all recent checkins (just your own, not including friends).  The documentation is quite awful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use their [API Explorer](http://gowalla.com/api/explorer) to see what's available in terms of the API. It's pretty neat and serves as nice documentation, just look at the [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) style URLs.

Here's basic code to get the last 5 checkins. You will need an API Key.

```
$username = 'sco';
$api_key = 'f6cd524ac9c4413abfb41d7123757d9';
$checkin_num = 5;
$url = "http://api.gowalla.com/users/{$username}/stamps?limit={$checkin_num}";

// setup curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array (
    "Accept: application/json",
    "X-Gowalla-API-Key: {$api_key}",
));
$body = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$json = json_decode($body, true);
foreach($json['stamps'] as $stamp) {
    print $stamp['spot']['name'] . '<br/>';
    print "<pre>";
    print_r($stamp);
    print "</pre>";
}
```

Here's what a checkin `'stamp'` object looks like:

```
Array
(
    [spot] => Array
        (
            [image_url] => http://static.gowalla.com/categories/24-standard.png
            [url] => /spots/19890
            [lat] => 38.9989524833
            [address] => Array
                (
                    [locality] => Kansas City
                    [region] => MO
                )

            [lng] => -94.5939345333
            [name] => The GAF Pub & Grille
        )

    [first_checkin_at] => 2010-06-12T19:16:57+00:00
    [checkins_count] => 1
    [last_checkin_at] => 2010-06-12T19:16:57+00:00
)
```

Comment: This gives you the "stamps" - you have one stamp for every distinct location you've checked in at. This doesn't however give you each checkin - also it doesn't give you the message associated with the checkin.

Comment: Right ibz, the answer is geared toward how to use PHP and cURL to get at the data, and I also refer the questioner to the API Explorer so he can get a sense of the different data that's available. If you feel like my answer needs edits or clarifications, please feel free to add! Thank you.

Comment: @artlung Don't know what the original intent of the question was - if it was about how to call Gowalla API from PHP, then your answer is great. However I came to this question hoping I can find a way to get the actual checkins - which seems impossible to do by using the API calls described in the API explorer. :( Yes, I found a way to do it after all, and posted the answer here.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://api.gowalla.com/users/USERNAME/events to get all checkins for a user. Use the `page` parameter to get results beyond the first page. Don't forget to pass the `Accept` header with the `application/json` value, or Gowalla will simply return 500 error.

Comment: Bwah, Gowalla just released version 4 - old API still works but doesn't seem to catch checkins created on version 4 clients!